# how can I use ui-keypress along ng-sumit?

Tags: angularjs, forms, ng-submit

I have a form like this

```
<form name="job" ng-submit="createJob(job,job_)" novalidate>

<!-- some other code -->

<!-- add new requirement to job_.requirement array on-enter --> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="requirement" ui-keypress="{13:'addRequirement(job_)'}">

<!-- display requirements  -->

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="requirement in job_.requirement track by $index" >{{requirement.name}}</li>
</ul>

<!-- submit entire form  -->
<button type="submit">Create Job</button>

</form>
```

because of using `ui-keypress` (to add new requirement on key-press=> 13) with `ng-sumbit` when ever I enter new requirement the form get submitted. I there any method to get rid of that ? 
created a demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/9uabjqhb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-keyup to submit form on click of enter button

```
<form name="job" ng-submit="createJob(job,job_)" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13  && createJob(job,job_);" novalidate>

<!-- some other code -->

<!-- add new requirement to job_.requirement array on-enter --> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="requirement" ui-keypress="{13:'addRequirement(job_)'}">

<!-- display requirements  -->

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="requirement in job_.requirement track by $index" >{{requirement.name}}</li>
</ul>

<!-- submit entire form  -->
<button type="submit">Create Job</button>

</form>
```

Comment: no it is not working; updated question with demo fiddle